# kivy : kvlan register fails

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to register a root (AClock) defined in kvlang with a python class 'AClock). Then I am running the app. But nothing shown. What is my mistake please ?

```
# File: main.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 

KV = '''
AClock:
  orientation: 'vertical'
  Label:
    color: 1,0,1,1
    text: '00:00:00'

'''


class AClock(BoxLayout):
     pass

class myApp(App):
     pass

Factory.register('Aclock',cls=AClock)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Builder.load_string(KV)
    myApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `load_string()` method returns a `Widget` (if the string defines a root `Widget` as your does), but you must return that `Widget` in the `build()` method of the `App`.

Here is a modified version of your code that dos that:

```
# File: main.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

KV = '''
AClock:
  orientation: 'vertical'
  Label:
    color: 1,0,1,1
    text: '00:00:00'

'''


class AClock(BoxLayout):
     pass

class myApp(App):
     def build(self):
         return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```